# get Iframe Horizontal scrollbar position javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scrollbar

It may looks Casual question, But I am spending long time for this.

I am loading local HTML file in IFRAME & I enable Horizontal navigation using

```
overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;
```

So, I want to know current horizontal scroll bar position

```
var Iframe = document.getElementById("IframeId");
var pos = Iframe.scrollLeft;
              &
vat pos = Iframe.document.body.scrollLeft;
```

Both are not worked for me. help me out for this

Comment: Pro tip: finding stuff like this is much easier if you have the luxury of using the Chrome dev tools. Of course if you're stuck with IE, then no such luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body` is within the `iframe` window, not within the `iframe` element. You can refer to the correct element like this:

```
var Iframe = document.getElementById("IframeId").contentWindow;
var pos = Iframe.document.body.scrollLeft;
```

Or more cross-browser way using `frames` collection:

```
var Iframe = window.frames['IframeId'];
var pos = Iframe.document.body.scrollLeft;
```

**EDIT**

In IE10 the `scrollLeft` property needs to be read from `document.documentElement`, hence:

```
var pos = Iframe.document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

Comment: `Iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollLeft` seems to work as well.

Comment: @Jondlm Yep, but `contentDocument` and `contentWindow` are not available for older browsers.

Comment: @Teemu It is giving value zero in both cases even if it is scrolled to right. FYI I am using IE 10

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust scrollbars of an iframe.

```
iframe{ width: XXpx; height: XXpx; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Try this.

Comment: I don't want to adjust scrollbars. I want to get position of Iframe scrollbar. Can you help me for this